# Forbidden to create a folder via Box API

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to create a folder via Box API. Here is how my request looks like:

```
-------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer [hidden]
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.14.1-beta (gzip)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 36

-------------- REQUEST BODY ----------
{"name":"test2","parent":{"id":"0"}}

-------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 21:15:53 GMT
Content-Length: 224
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store

-------------- RESPONSE BODY----------
{"type":"error","status":403,"code":"access_denied_insufficient_permissions","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Access denied - insufficient permission","request_id":"19725779175165d68967049"}
```

Can somebody explain what is wrong with my request? In the response to other requests with the same Bearer header I receive correct results:

```
-------------- REQUEST  --------------
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer [hidden]
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.14.1-beta (gzip)

-------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 21:15:53 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

And my application is configured to ask for read and write permissions.

Comment: Are you able to create a file?

Comment: Are you able to use this same bearer token to make a successful request in curl or POSTMAN?

Comment: Curl helped me to find the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you change URL from

> https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0

to

> https://api.box.com/2.0/folders

Comment: Yes, exactly. Funny that I've just found the same answer myself a second ago. But yours is still correct. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For Creating folder in Box.net using C#.net

static string folderCreation(string APIKey, string authToken)
    {

```
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders";
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    string Headers = string.Format("Bearer {0}", authToken);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", Headers);
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"name\":\"Youka\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"0\"}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    return response.Content;



}
```